# Runtime error with Angular 8, interface is not defined

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-material, angular-cli, typescript3.0

We recently attempted an upgrade from Angular 7 to Angular 8. Had some issues when building, eg had to rename a definition from d.ts to .ts but got it to compile and we though everything was fine. But when running the site we got a runtime error:
`ErrorDialogSettings is not defined`, `ErrorDialogSettings` is an interface which is used in a constructor as a parameter for a dialog component, both class and interface are declared in the same file. The generated output contains the following `{ type: ErrorDialogSettings, decorators: [{ type: _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["Inject"], args: [_angular_material_dialog__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["MAT_DIALOG_DATA"],] }] }`. What I found weird is that the interface is referenced there. What could be the problem? I can't figure out what has changed, it could be everything from Webpack to Typescript.

We are running Typescript 3.4.5, Angular Materials 8 and the Angular CLI 8

Comment: I also faced this same type of issue, interface is not defined for angular-calendar. This error occcured suddenly. Seems like some issue in web pack.

Comment: I would say so as well since it's compiling correctly and all

Comment: I had the same error. There's the discussion with fix — https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14876

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the CLI, updating to @angular/cli 8.0.6 resolved the issue. Thank you Londeren!